# Sonos GetPlaylist API return "404 Not Found"

Tags: sonos

This is my list of Sonos playlists associated to the household obtained by calling the api

*/households/{householdId}/playlists*

```
    "playlists": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Playlist Sonos A",
        "type": "playlist",
        "trackCount": 5
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Playlist Sonos B",
        "type": "playlist",
        "trackCount": 3
    }
]
```

I would like to get informations about tracks of a specific playlist. 
I read from the Sonos documentation that I have to call the api below passing the playlistId in the body.

*/households/{householdId}/playlists/getPlaylist*

```
{ "playlistId" : "2" }
```

but it returns always **404 Not Found**

{
    "errorCode": "ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_COMMAND"
}

Comment: This is a bug that we are working on. Once resolved, I'll update here and also post this known issue to the developer.sonos.com/blog. Unfortunately, I can't give an estimate on how long this will take to resolve.